# Alfresco Rule to Remove (unlink) Category from File

Tags: categories, alfresco, rules

In Alfresco users can use rules to link categories to files. There isn't an option to unlink categories from a file.

How do I programmatically remove (unlink) categories from a file without removing the classification aspect?

If a script is required, do you have an example?

I am using Alfresco 7.0 Share/Community version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look into the node browser:
Alfresco stores the categories on a node as an array of nodeRefs to the category nodes.

If you want to remove specific category from a node you need to save the array without the nodeRef for that category.

To illustrate that: the following example removes the category `/Regions/EUROPE` from a given document node:

```js
var categories= document.properties["cm:categories"];

for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    var categoryPath = categories[i].displayPath + '/' + categories[i].name;
    logger.log(categoryPath);
    
    if (categoryPath == '/categories/General/Regions/EUROPE'){
        categories.splice(i, 1)
    }
}

document.properties["cm:categories"]= categories;
document.save();
```